# Evaluate $\int_1^{\sqrt3}\left( x^{2x^2+1}+\ln x^{\left(2x^{2x^2+1}\right)}\right)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate $\displaystyle\int_1^{\sqrt3}\left( x^{2x^2+1}+\ln x^{\left(2x^{2x^2+1}\right)}\right)dx$

I first thought of putting $x=\cos\theta$ but then realized it would have worked if we had $2x^2-1$, not now.

Then I put $y=2x^2+1$, thus the second term became $\ln x^{2y}$ but of course I needed to replace $x$ too. Since that won't make the expression any simpler, I abandoned that thought.

If I write the second term as $(2x^{2x^2+1}\ln x)$, it is not helping either.

I tried using $\displaystyle\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$ but in vain.

I tried writing $x^2=t$ to rationalize the limits but couldn't really conclude that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{1}^{\sqrt3} \left(x^{2x^2+1}+\ln(x^{2x^{2x^2+1}})\right) dx 
= \int_{1}^{\sqrt3} x^{2x^2+1}\left(2\ln(x)+1\right) dx$$

Substitute $u=x^{x^2}$ then,
$$\frac{du}{dx}=x^{x^2}(2x\ln x +x)$$

Substituting $$dx=\frac{du}{x^{x^2}(2x\ln x +x)}$$ in the simplified intergral you get,

$$\int u \,du$$
$$= \frac{u^2}{2} + C = \frac{x^{2x^2}}{2}+C$$
applying limits gives the value of the given definite integral as $13$.

Answer (score 5):

Notice that the integrand simplifies to

$$x^{2x^2+1}+2x^{2x^2+1}\ln x = \frac{1}{2}x^{2x^2}\left(2x+4x\ln x\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left(x^{2x^2}\right)'$$

therefore the integral becomes

$$\int_1^{\sqrt{3}}x^{2x^2+1}+\ln x^{2x^{2x^2+1}}dx = \frac{1}{2}x^{2x^2}\Bigr|_1^{\sqrt{3}} = 13$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively note that,

$$ ~ \displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \left(x^{2x^2}\right) = 2 x^{(2 x^2 + 1)} (1 + 2 \ln x)$$

So using substitution $~t = x^{2x^2},~$ the integration simplifies to

$$ \frac{1}{2} \displaystyle \int_1^{27} dt = 13$$